# Segmentation fault when using command line arguments

Tags: c, file-io, command-line, getopt

I am trying to get the input and output file names through command line arguments. I am just using getopt (tell me if there is a better way) and I got  `segmentation fault`

I am sure that the segmentation fault is caused by the name of the input file. Some thing is going wrong when I take the name of the input file from the command line.

Here is my code:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char const *inFile = NULL; //I think the error is here
                               //an inFile that doesn't exist
                               //would cause a segmentation fault
    char const *outFile = "outfile.txt";
    double val;
    int xFlg= 0;
    int c;
    char *rm; //I need this for strtod, but I can use atoi instead

    while ( (c = getopt (argc, argv, "xo")) != -1 ) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'x':
                val = strtod(optarg, &rm);
                xFlg = 1;
                break;
            case 'o':
                outFile = optarg;
                break;
            default:
                help(); //void function that prints help
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        rm=NULL;
    }
    inFile = *(argv + optind);

    fread code
    .
    .
    .
    call function
    .
    .
    .
    fwrite code
}
```

I am sure that there is no problem with my freads and fwrites because if I take the name of inFile and outFile using scanf, everything works perfectly and I don't get a segmentation error.

I am using the value of `xflg` to decide whether to run my function or not. `val` is the value that my function takes.

Here is my function:

```
void xFunc (input1, input2, val, xFlg) {
    if (xFlg == 1) {
        function code
        .
        .
        .
    } else {
    return; //don't run the function if the user doesn't type -x
            //into command line.
            //I don't know if this is the proper way to do this.
    }
}
```

This is what I want to achieve:

**./run -x 3.14 -o outputfilename.txt inputfilename.txt**

Edit:

If I do the following to get the input file name, no segmentation fault happens:

```
char inFile[100];
printf("Name of input file: \n");
scanf("%99s",somestring);
```

Comment: Where exactly does it crash ?

Comment: It compiles with no errors and it crashes when opening the inFile. I tried taking in the name of inFile using scanf and it works.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code where the crash occurs.

Comment: what is command "like" argument?

Comment: What is `optind` ?

Comment: Correct this `scanf ("%s", &inputfile);` **->** `scanf ("%s", inputfile);` . Problem will occur after this statement.

Comment: I added this part to the question `./run -x 3.14 -o outputfilename.txt inputfilename.txt` This is basically what I want to achieve.

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you run under a debugger?  Have you tried printing out the values of the command-line arguments you parsed?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: `#include <unistd.h>

       int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[],
                  const char *optstring);

       extern char *optarg;
       extern int optind, opterr, optopt;`

Comment: Try `"x:o:"` as the optstring argument in the `getopt` call. Options that expect an argument need a colon after the option letter in the optstring argument.

Comment: _never_ use scanf("%s",somestring), use scanf("%99s",somestring), or better fgets(somestring,100,stdin)

Comment: You want to start using a debugger, really!

Comment: Very sorry about this mess. I got it to work eventually. Should have been more patient before posting.

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason you why cannot assign `inFile = *(argv + optind)` (or `inFile = argv[optind]`) **as long as you check that `optind < argc` before doing so**. (Actually, `argv[argc]` will be `NULL`, but `argv[argc+1]` will result in undefined behavior.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is two fold:

```
char const *inFile = NULL;
......
inFile = *(argv + optind);
```

Once you initialized a `const char*` you cannot assign it another value. So to fix this you can try one of the following:

```
.....
 char const * inFile = *(argv + optind);
.....
```

If you don't need the inFile pointer up to the point where you initialize it this should be fine.

OR

```
char inFile[20]; //whatever size you need
......
strcpy(inFile, *(argv + optind));
```

This way you can change the file pointer, if you need to

Comment: This got rid of the segmentation fault problem. I am now able to read the inFile and I confirmed this by printing out some values from within inFile. But my function xFunc isn't working.

Comment: can't say much about that...I don't see it being called anywhere in the code (sure...you say something about this in the comments but that won't do), nor to I see a function prototype or anything to go on.....anyway consider that it may not be the function code but the value of the arguments you provide  that are not what you expect...

Comment: @Pandrei: `char const *inFile` is the same as `const char *inFile`. It declares `inFile` as a pointer to constant char, not a constant pointer to char. You can assign to the `inFile` variable after declaring it, but you cannot assign to `*inFile` or to `inFile[index]`.